# AngularFire 2 v5 How to Retrieve Data once?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to pull data from firebase just once.
With this code it subscribes and watches for changes and updates value realtime.

```
this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).snapshotChanges().map(action => {
      const $key = action.payload.key;
      const data = { $key, ...action.payload.val() };
      return data;

    })).subscribe(profile => {

      this.profileData = profile;


      console.log(this.profileData.username); // this is working.

    });
```

I was trying something like this but its not working

```
this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`)).take(1).subscribe(profile =>{

console.log(profile.username);

}));
```

Comment: The `take(1)` should be working, see: [Just get the value once with no subscription](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/456#issuecomment-241509299).

Comment: this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`)).take(1);
console.log(this.profileData.username);            this returns undefined ?

Comment: with console.log(this.profileData) i got this : http://prntscr.com/h0waiy

Comment: `profileData` is an Observable as we can see from your image, you need to subscribe to it, to be able to console log it

Answer (score 0):

When you are using your own observables you have to care about unsubscribe.

Angular components have a lot of lifecycle hooks like ngOnInit, ngOnChange etc. You have also function ngOnDestroy and good practise is to unsubscribe your observables in that hook.

I think if you want to fetch data only once the best option is to call function where you unsubscribe. Here you have link with more info about: [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: Thanks.what about the second code I posted? why I cant retrieve data once ? ( btw first code is working perfect but its not once )

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is get the subscription and unsubscribe once you received a value

```
let subs$ = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => 
 this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).snapshotChanges().map(action => {
  const $key = action.payload.key;
  const data = { $key, ...action.payload.val() };
  return data;

})).subscribe(profile => {

  this.profileData = profile;
  subs$.unsubscribe()



  console.log(this.profileData.username); // this is working.

});
```